# How to use update with group by

Tags: sql, sql-update, h2

I want to change the sum(value) where name='Albanit' but when I use **group by name** an error is shown.

```
update bill 
   set value=(( select sum(value) from bill where name='Albanit' group by name) -10)  
where name='Albanit' 
group by name;
```

I am using H2 database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove group by

```
update bill set value=((select sum(value) from bill 
                        where name='Albanit') -10 )
                        where name='Albanit'
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need the `group by`?  Does this do what you want?

```
update bill 
   set value = value - 10
where name = 'Albanit' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need group by name column as you've specify a particular name in where clause

```
update bill set value=(( select sum(value) from bill where name='Albanit') -10) 
where name='Albanit'
```